# Connecting graphql api backend link with Next13 self signed certificate

Tags: magento2, graphql, pwa

I'm having some issues with connecting our magento backend url with Next js App
The api request isn't working correctly and give self signed certificate error
My apollo client

```
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import { concatPagination } from '@apollo/client/utilities'
let apolloClient;

function createApolloClient() {
    const uri = process.browser
    ? new URL('/graphql', location.href)
    : new URL('/graphql', process.env.MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL).href

    return new ApolloClient({
        ssrMode: !process.browser,
        credentials: 'include',
        link: new HttpLink({
          uri,
          credentials: 'include', // Additional fetch() options like `credentials` or `headers`
        }),
        cache: new InMemoryCache({
          typePolicies: {
            Query: {
              fields: {
                allPosts: concatPagination(),
              },
            },
          },
        }),
        name: 'ssr',
        defaultOptions: { query: { errorPolicy: 'all' } },
      })
    }

export function initializeApollo(initialState = null) {

    const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient();

    /* If your page has Next.js data fetching methods that use Apollo Client, the initial stategets hydrated here*/ 

    if (initialState) {
        // Get existing cache, loaded during client side data fetching
        const existingCache = _apolloClient.extract();

    /* Restore the cache using the data passed from  
getStaticProps/getServerSideProps combined with the existing 
    cached data */
      _apolloClient.cache.restore({ ...existingCache, ...initialState});
    }
    // For SSG and SSR always create a new Apollo Client
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _apolloClient;
    // Create the Apollo Client once in the client
    if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient;

    return _apolloClient;
}

export function useApollo(initialState) {
    const store = 
    useMemo(() => initializeApollo(initialState),[initialState]);
    return store;
}

export const client = initializeApollo();
```

And layout providers

```
"use client";
import Footer from "./components/main/Footer";
import Header from "./components/main/Header";
import "./globals.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { useStyleConfig } from "../app/peregrine/lib/talons/Configuration/useStyle";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { useApollo } from "./lib/apolloClient";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const apolloClient = useApollo();

  const { applyStyles } = useStyleConfig();
  useEffect(() => {
    applyStyles();
  }, []);
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Header />
        <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>{children}</ApolloProvider>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

next.config

```
const path = require("path");
const { URL } = require("url");

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
      loader: "graphql-tag/loader",
    });

    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      "~": path.resolve(__dirname),
    };

    return config;
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/graphql/:pathname*",
        destination: new URL("graphql", process.env.MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL).href,
      },

      {
        source: "/lms/:path*",
        destination: process.env.CSR_URL,
      },
      {
        source: "/csr/:path*",
        destination: process.env.LMS_URL,
      },
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        destination: process.env.KONG_URL,
      },
      {
        source: "/css|env|logo/:path*",
        destination: process.env.MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL,
      },
      {
        source: "/graphql|rest|media/:path*",
        destination: process.env.MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

I'm getting this error all the time
[image]